# Is there any way to combine bootstrap4 with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Like in the question. I am new in web developement, I just getting comfortable with bootstrap. In bootstrap4 I have found  this code to get proper scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When I try to combine these links with:

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am still not able to use jqueryUi functions. What should I do ?

Comment: What do mean by "not able" ?

Comment: With this 4 scripts above Im not able for example to use any animations from jQureyUI. I dont event get hints from brackets with jQueryUI functions.